# Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-middleware'

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm making a nodejs + expressjs server, and a react fat client (SPA). After I install this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "express-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some basic ReactJS",
  "author": "Greg",
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

I got this error when I run `DEBUG=express-react:* & npm start` command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-middleware'
```

My app.js was generated by the express-generator:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const webpackmiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const compiler = webpack(config);

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.use(webpackmiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: {colors: true},
}));
.....
```

It confuses me.. I defined the `webpack-dev-middleware` package in the package.json file, but it said its not found.. why?
Have anybody met this problem before?

Thanks for the responses / advices in advance!

Comment: did you ran `npm install` after package.json changes?

Comment: try running `npm install --dev`

Comment: Ohh that was the solution @AyushGupta ! The `--dev` tag solved the problem. If you write that comment in answer I 'll accept that solution! :)

Comment: Do you have `NODE_ENV` defined in your environment? `npm install --dev` is generally synonymous with `npm install` unless `NODE_ENV` is defined as `production`.  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install (search for --production)

Comment: Hi @jostrander! Thx for the comment. I defined and it is production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webpack-dev-middleware` is mentioned in your `devDependencies`, not `dependencies`.

If your `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`, `npm install` only installs  production dependencies and excludes development dependencies:

To install `devDependencies`, run:

```
npm install --dev
```